# Error connecting to Access DB using Rscript.exe

Tags: ms-access, rodbc, rscript

R version: 3.4.4 - 32 bit / OS: Windows 7 Enterprise SP 1 - 64 bit

```
library("RODBC")

TodaysDate  <- Sys.Date()
StartTime   <- Sys.time()
currentUser <- Sys.getenv("USERNAME")
tmpDir      <- Sys.getenv("TEMP")
sysHour     <- hour(Sys.time())

if (sysHour > 12){
  sysHour = (sysHour - 12) 
} 

outFile <- paste(tmpDir, "\\Production_", TodaysDate, "_", sysHour,"_PM.html", sep = "")

channel <- odbcConnectAccess2007("C:\\Users\\admin\\Documents\\AccessDB1.accdb")

QueryOutput <- sqlQuery(channel, "SELECT * FROM HourlyAnalystProduction;")

close(channel)

...
```

> Rscript.exe --vanilla C:\Users\admin\Documents\Prod.R

Command prompt output:
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] 
Data source name not found and no default driver specified
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed

Error in sqlQuery(channel, "SELECT * FROM HourlyA
nalystProduction;") :
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel
Execution halted

This code works perfectly using RStudio. However, running this using rscript results in ODBC connection failed error. I get the same error if I run the code using R.exe with the -f option.

Any ideas for a fix would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running using the same bitness as Access? This error is common if you're using 64-bits R and 32-bits Access or the inverse of that.

Comment: My Office 2013 is 32 bit and so is R. Unless rscript.exe defaults to 64 bit... ? That would explain why the code works perfectly from R and not using rscript.exe

Comment: Just print `R.version$arch` if you're not sure...

Comment: Using the version option of rscript, I got this:
\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin>rscript --version
R scripting front-end version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)

Comment: Typing R at the command prompt and then the version cmd, I got this:
> R.version$arch
[1] "i386"

Comment: That's certainly strange... I'm at a loss then. If they're the same bitness and version, there's absolutely no reason for RStudio to behave differently from rscript. Same machine that has 32-bit Access installed, right? Those slashes and that path seem odd for Windows